# Embedded Youtube video player vs html5/flash video player in web application

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, html5-video

Many web application which have videos to show. For example [The New Boston](https://www.thenewboston.com/) uses the embedded Youtube player. Is there any advantage using embedded Youtube video player over implementing our own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros:

- No need to pay for hosting and content delivery
- Allows for quickly bootstraping new ideas
- Youtube makes content much more discoverable. Users watching similar content will be recommended your content as well. In this way they can find about your service.

Cons:

- No way to differentiate between paying and non-paying customers. What if you want to offer premium content to your paying customers?
- Youtube takes the lions share of any advertising revenue.
- No UI customization.
- Sometimes youtube censors things they don't want for whatever reason.
- If your website offers its users to leave comments or a "like" button then users may get confused over which comments to use - the ones in youtube or the ones in your website.
- Support for live broadcasting is a not as good.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage to using the youtube player is that you have access to their servers to stream the video as opposed to whatever hosting server you are using. Realistically you have the same control over how it appears within the page either way. Just keep in mind you will need to deliver multiple file types if you go the HTML5 video tag route.

Comment: Is that mean that we have to host our video on youtube as well?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use the youtube player, it would be uploaded to a youtube account.

Comment: Then what is the meaning to create web video library just upload all the videos on youtube and user will directly goto youtube for access to those videos.

Comment: As far as I know, its better to let a video hosting service like youtube or vimeo do the work for you. The advantage to hosting your own video is that it does look a bit more professional.